# Is it legal to discriminate against people over a certain age?

Tags: england-and-wales, discrimination, is-x-legal, age, equality-act-2010

A restaurant reserves certain items on its menu for individuals under a certain age.

The equality act 2010 specifically makes allowances for age discrimination against people under the age of 18. But not for discriminating against individuals over a certain age threshold.

What is the standing of this practice?

Comment: Well asked, yes (asi realised after posting) Answered, arguably not.